# Python convert array dimensions with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a JPG image with a shape of (1, 48, 48, 3), 
I want to convert it to the shape of (1, 48, 48, 1)
How can I do it ?

Please help

Comment: What type of conversion are you going to do?

Comment: I only need to change the last axis to be 1 and not 3

Answer (score -1):

thank you all!
I solve it with

img = img.mean(axis=-1) 
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=3)

Comment: You can add `keepdims=True` to the `mean()` call, then the second statement is no longer necessary.